# ansible template expands on OSX, not on Linux

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to build a playbook using set_fact but the template seems
to expand when I test locally on OSX but not when I invoke ansible via
Jenkins on Linux. Here's the line:

```
- set_fact:
    snapshot_id: "production-snapshot-{{ 2000000000 | random | to_uuid | replace('-', '') | truncate(12, end='') }}"
```

When I test this on OSX the value gets populated correctly with something like
"production-snapshot-4d378e43eede". When I invoke this in Jenkins on Linux the
value is "production-snapshot-". There's no other output or error
message besides the truncated value.

Both environments use ansible 2.3.0. Linux uses Python 2.7.5 and OSX has Python 2.7.13.

Any idea what's going on here? Is this a bug?

Comment: Try using `random()` instead of just `random`.

Comment: @Jack I tried removing the random call entirely and that didn't help address this issue.

Comment: What's with the `truncate(12)`?  That gets rid of the uuid part.

Comment: As I understand it the truncate strips off anything beyond 12 characters.

Comment: You need `truncate(12, 'true', end=''`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the `truncate` command.

"If the second parameter is true the filter will cut the text at length. Otherwise it will discard the last word." [Template Designer Documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/)

Change your play to:

```
- set_fact:
    snapshot_id: "production-snapshot-{{ 2000000000 | random | to_uuid | replace('-', '') | truncate(12, 'true', end='') }}"
```

Comment: One clarification, how does the seemingly broken truncate() call work on OSX?

Comment: I do not run OSX, so I cannot say.  I was able to reproduce his error in Linux and fix it.